# why I can not create new object in Btrace unsafe mode?

Tags: btrace

In Btrace UserGuide(https://kenai.com/projects/btrace/pages/UserGuide ) it refers 'BTrace Restrictions' , and also refers in unsafe mode no ‘BTrace Restrictions’

BTrace Restrictions
      can not create new objects.
      can not create new arrays.
      can not throw exceptions.
      ... ...

Supported Arguments
      unsafe - do not check for btrace restrictions violations (true/false)

in my btrace shell, I already set -Dcom.sun.btrace.unsafe=true，but even can't create new object, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mark the script itself for unsafe execution by using **@BTrace(unsafe=true)**

Comment: Thank you , I also get the answer from offical, the offical document is incomplete   https://kenai.com/jira/browse/BTRACE-105